# Ansible InventoryManager subset method throwing TypeError

Tags: python, ansible

I am using python to run ansible-playbook programmatically. I trying to test with simple playbook that ping localhost.

But when I use subset method from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager I am getting NoneType error

Below my code

```
from ansible import context
from ansible.module_utils.common.collections import ImmutableDict
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager

loader = DataLoader()
inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources="localhost,")
inventory.subset('x.x.x.x')
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
variable_manager._extra_vars = {'customer': 'test'}
passwords = {}
context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(tags={}, listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False,
                                    module_path=None, forks=100, private_key_file=None,
                                    ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=False,
                                    become_method='sudo', become_user='root', verbosity=True, check=False, start_at_task=None)

playbook = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=['/Users/Admin/Desktop/Repositories/ansible-playbooks/test.yml'],
                            inventory=inventory,
                            variable_manager=variable_manager,
                            loader=loader, passwords=passwords)

playbook.run()
```

Error I get

```
$ python3 testAnsible.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testAnsible.py", line 14, in <module>
    inventory.subset('x.x.x.x')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I am using python3.8.2 and ansible 2.9.6
Could you please help me to fix this? I took a look at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/b4d66c49914cdf6744f72692874830c03559b2f9/lib/ansible/inventory/manager.py#L600 there is subset method. I do not understood why I am getting Type Error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like bug with anisble 2.9.6

I have upgraded it to 2.9.7 and error is not more.